# Generate an infinite stream of tuples

Tags: java, math, java-8, java-stream

I need to generate an infinite stream of tuples, which satisfy the equation:

> 2 * a * a + b * b = c * c

I am just starting with java 8 and am unsure how to achieve this.
I have an interface for the tuple:

```
public interface Tuple {
    /**
     * @return The value of A
     */
    int getA();

    /**
     * @return The value of B
     */
    int getB();

    /**
     * @return The value of C
     */
    int getC();
}
```

And so far I have this method:

```
public static Stream<Tuple> generateABCTuples() {
    Supplier<Tuple> aTuple = (Supplier<Tuple>) generateABCTuples();
    Stream<Tuple> myList = Stream.generate(aTuple)
                                 .sorted();
    return myList;
}
```

However, i am unsure how to satisfy the above equation.
Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be less about Java and the `Stream` API and more about _math_.

Comment: This also seems to have written the most basic part, and left the difficult part of the homework up to us.  And don't name a stream `myList`.

Comment: I think this is hard to do with `Stream.generate()`. You can do it with `Stream.iterate()`. Think how you would find all the solutions to the equation using three nested loops, and adapt this idea to write an instance method `Tuple next() { ... }`. Then you can get an infinite stream of all possible solutions using `Stream.iterate(new Tuple(0, 0, 0), Tuple::next);`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's do a little research (using non-negative values)
`2*a^2+b^2=c^2`
`2*a^2 = c^2 - b^2 = (c-b)*(c+b)`
We can see that b and c must be both odd or both even. Anyway, right part is divisible by 4, so left is divisible by 4 too, and a is even. 
Another condition: `c >= b`
Let's

```
a = 2*p
u=(c-b)/2
v=(c+b)/2 [with v>=u]
```

so

```
b=v-u  
c=v+u
8*p^2 = 4 * u * v
2*p^2 = u * v
```

Now we can take any value of p, factorize 2*p^2, find possible factors u and v, and get corresponding a, b, c values (probably not unique).
Example:

```
p=0  =>  u=0, v=any value, all c=b pairs are the solutions 2*0+k^2=k^2
p=1  =>  v=2, u=1  a=2 b=1 c=3   2*4+1=9  
p=2  =>  v=8, u=1  a=4 b=7 c=9   2*16+49=81  //and the second factorization:
         v=4, u=2  a=4 b=2 c=6    2*16+4=36
and so on...
```

Of course, every triplet element might be negative: `a=-2 b=1 c=-3` is valid solution